# I don’t know Chinese, so can someone help me figure out what this sentence says?

Tags: translation, meaning

[image: sentence]

I don’t know Chinese, but I want to know what the sentence in the attached image says in. I only have the sentence in an image so hopefully you can see it. I apologize for the low picture quality. I hope it doesn’t make it too hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

It can be translated as below:

"Traveller, where are you going to?"

Or similarly, "Tourist, where is your destination?"

旅行者, 你將去往何方?

旅行者 - Traveller (旅遊者 - tourist)

你 - You

將 - About to, intend to, prepared to (used to indicate a future event, future tense)

去, 往 - both mean "going to" or "toward", I would eliminate one of these words for clarity.

何方 - where